# COUNT of rows grouped by multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

Here is the example:

```
SELECT Item.purchase_transaction_id, ItemType.item_type, COUNT(Item.id) 
FROM Item GROUP BY Item.purchase_transaction_id, Item.item_type_id
```

So after this query, I want to get the Total quantity of the results of the row or maybe you can call it `COUNT` of the result. I don't know how to do this with SQL but with SqlAlchemy I can do it like this

```
q = db.session.query(Item.purchase_transaction_id, ItemType.item_type, 
func.count(Item.id)).group_by(Item.purchase_transaction_id, Item.item_type_id)
```

and to get the `count` I just call `q.count()`, but I'm guessing this one is not efficient, since you call the query first and then only after that count the results.

So, is there any efficient way to get the `COUNT` of rows from `GROUP BY` multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Item.purchase_transaction_id, ItemType.item_type, COUNT(Item.id) 
      FROM Item
      GROUP BY Item.purchase_transaction_id, Item.item_type_id
     ) i;
```

If the values are not `NULL` and if your underlying database supports it, then you can also do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Item.purchase_transaction_id, ItemType.item_type)
FROM Item;
```

(Otherwise, you can concatenate the values together and still use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.)

Comment: As for the first one, does sql execute and find all of the records and then calculate the result? would it be efficient enough? As for the 2nd one I got this error `wrong number of arguments to function COUNT():`

Comment: @kingathur61 . . . Not all databases support `count(distinct)` with multiple arguments.  Another option is something like:  `count(diistnct concat(Item.purchase_transaction_id, ':', ItemType.item_type))`.